# UIInputViewSetPlacementInvisible placementWithPlacement Should not be called with an invisible placement on Flutter ios app

Tags: ios, flutter

When I deploy the app developed with Flutter on a real iPhone, I encounter an issue.

**This issue only occurs on a physical iPhone**, and not on the iOS simulator or a physical Android phone.

The problem arises when I try to unfocus the soft keyboard using the most common method:

```
GestureDetector(onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
```

This results in the following error message:

**[Assert] +[UIInputViewSetPlacementInvisible placementWithPlacement:]: Should not be called with an invisible placement**

In fact, I receive this error message every time I unfocus the soft keyboard, including when tapping the back button on the scaffold.

You can replicate this behavior using the sample code provided below. However, despite extensive searching on the internet, I haven't been able to find much information about this issue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SecondPage(),
              ));
            },
            child: const Text('next page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It shouldn't have this error.